# Retaining a variable created during module import in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am trying to populate a dictionary with functions along with the name of the function contained in another file of the form:

{'fn_a': function fn_a at 0x000002239BDCB510, 'fn_b': function fn_b at 0x000002239BDCB268}.

I'm currently attempting to do it with a decorator so when the file containing the functions (definitions.py) is imported the dictionary is populated as follows. The problem is that dictionary is cleared once the import is complete.

definitions.py:

```
from main import formatter

@formatter
def fn_a(arg):
    return arg

@formatter
def fn_b(arg):
    return arg
```

main.py:

```
available_functions = {}

def formatter(func):
    # work out function name and write to func_name
    func_name=str(func).split()[1]
    available_functions[func_name] = func
    return func

import definitions
```

How can I keep the dictionary populated with values after the module import is finished?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using the FunctionType module to return the available functions from the imported module. It doesn't solve the problem within the conditions I specified above, but does work.

```
from types import FunctionType

available_functions = {}

def formatter(func):
    # work out function name and write to func_name
    #global available_functions
    func_name=str(func).split()[1]
    available_functions[func_name] = func
    return func

import definitions

funcs=[getattr(definitions, a) for a in dir(definitions)
  if isinstance(getattr(definitions, a), FunctionType)]

for i in funcs:
    formatter(i)
```